# Jq Convert multiple string inputs to one larger array without slurp or inputs

Tags: arrays, jq, reduce

I have:

Filter:

```
["key:\(.key)", "value:\(.value)"][]
```

Input:

```
{"key":"state","value":"pending"}
{"key":"options","value":"request"}
```

Output:

```
"key:state"
"value:pending"
"key:options"
"value:request"
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/9yq89orzL0

I want to convert the output `"key:state" "value:pending" "key:options" "value:request"` to array `["key:state", "value:pending", "key:options", "value:request"]`.

I tried `reduce . as $s ([]; .+[$s])` but this gives `["key:state"] ["value:pending"] ["key:options"] ["value:request"]`.

I want a solution *without* using `slurp` or `inputs`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a solution without using slurp or inputs.

Unfortunately, unless you’re willing to invoke jq twice, those are the only two options that jq has to offer, unless you allow `input`. And the same can be said of gojq and jaq.

If your input is JSONL (one JSON per line), then there are of course many obvious ways to preprocess the stream to achieve the "slurping" effect. Otherwise, you'd probably want to use a JSON-oriented tool, either to supplement jq, or to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `--null-input` and `input` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
  
jq --null-input '
def loop:
    .+(input|["key:\(.key)", "value:\(.value)"]) |
    . as $res |
    try loop catch $res ;
loop
' << EOF
{"key":"state","value":"pending"}
{"key":"options","value":"request"}
EOF
```

output:

```
[
  "key:state",
  "value:pending",
  "key:options",
  "value:request"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider this a very practical solution but you could switch the scope from the itemwise stream to an enveloping singleton by using a second call to `jq`, and an appropriate encoding for the transition, thus using `-j` and `-R` to write and read a single line of raw text. Technically, this fulfills your requirements (not using `slurp` or `inputs`), but is it worth it?

One such way could be to manually build a JSON array from already JSON-encoded parts by adding commas and brackets:

In the first instance, encode the items as JSON using `tojson`, and append a comma to each. In the second instance, remove the last character (the superfluous comma), wrap the string in brackets, and decode the ready JSON array using `fromjson`.

```sh
jq -j '"key:\(.key)", "value:\(.value)" | "\(tojson),"' | jq -R '"[\(.[:-1])]" | fromjson'
```

```json
[
  "key:state",
  "value:pending",
  "key:options",
  "value:request"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an elaboration on Philippe's answer.

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/C_C-xudpVQ

Filter

```
def to_array: .+[input] | . as $acc | try to_array catch $acc; to_array
```

Input

```
"foo is bar"
"goo is google"
"stack is over"
"over is flow"
```

Output

```
[
  "foo is bar",
  "goo is google",
  "stack is over",
  "over is flow"
]
```

In `to_array` function, on *each* iteration we add an `input` to a single array and save to `$acc` (aka 'accumulated') , until **there is no more `input`**, in which case we output the `$acc` up to that point (since `try` will fail in that case this will execute `catch` exp).